# May __init__ be used as normal method for initialization, not as constructor?

Tags: python, design-patterns, initialization, pep8

Sometimes it looks reasonable to use `__init__` as initialization method for already existing object, i.e.:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def set_state_from_file(self, file):
        x = parse_file(file)
        self.__init__(x)
```

As alternative to this implementation I see the following:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.init(x)        

    def init(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def set_state_from_file(self, file):
        x = parse_file(file)
        self.init(x)
```

It seems to me as over-complication of code. Is there any guideline on this situation?

**Update:** There is a case when it is definitely not an alternate constructor case: unpickling. During unpickling, pickle first creates an instance and only then sets its state.

Comment: Why not have a non-member function to parse the file, and create a new instance? It seems you'd have to re-write the class each time you wanted to initialise it from a different source, which violates the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Comment: @Peter Wood, what about `__init__` in `__setstate__`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`__init__` is not a constructor. It is an initialisation method, called *after* the instance was already constructed for you (the actual constructor method is called [`__new__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__)).

You can always call it again from your code if you need to re-initialise, this isn't a style violation. In fact, it is used in the Python standard library; see the [`multiprocessing.heap.Heap()` implementation](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/multiprocessing/heap.py#l223) for example:

```
def malloc(self, size):
    # return a block of right size (possibly rounded up)
    assert 0 <= size < sys.maxsize
    if os.getpid() != self._lastpid:
        self.__init__()                     # reinitialize after fork
```

or the [`threading.local` implementation](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/_threading_local.py#l194), which uses a context manager to defer initialisation.

There is otherwise nothing special about the `__init__` method itself. It is merely automatically called by `type.__call__` (after creating the instance with `instance = cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)`, `cls.__init__(instance, *args, **kwargs)` is called if it is available).

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Martjin's answer: a common pattern in Python is to use classmethods as factory methods, ie:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    @classmethod
    def from_file(cls, file):
        x = parse_file(file)
        return cls(x)


a1 = A(42)
a2 = A.from_file(open("/path/to/file"))
```

Comment: @Sklavit then obviously the "classmethod as alternate constructor" pattern is not what you need <g>

Comment: What has this got to do with reusing the `__init__` method on an existing instance?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters this answer is also the answer for the question above.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I've seen peoples reusing `__init__` from another method when what they really wanted was an alternate constructor...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: sure, but that issue is orthogonal to wether or not there is a style issue with reusing the method.

Comment: @MartijnPieters sure, but in case we really had an XY problem mentionning the alternate constructor pattern doesn't hurt.

Comment: Sure, but then explain that in your answer :-) *It looks like you really wanted an alternative constructor. If so, the Pythonic pattern is to use a classmethod* or words to that effect.

Comment: @MartijnPieters well I thought it was obviously implied - but I may assume too much ;-)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers There is case when it is definitely not alternate constructor: unpickling. During unpickling, pickle first create an instance and only then sets its state.

Answer (score 0):

I found some differences between `__init__` and 'normal' methods:

1., `__init__` is not allowed to return anything: TypeError will be raised.

2., If `__init__` raises error, `__del__` will be called:
UPDATE by Martijn Pieters: this is only for constructor calls, not for generic usage, see comments below.

```
 class A(object):
     def __init__(self):
           print('__init__')
           raise ValueError('__init__ error')
           pass

    def method(self):
        raise ValueError('method error')

    def __del__(self):
        print("__del__")

def main():
    try:
        a = A()
        a.method()
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
    print('exit main')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    print('end of file')
```

will output:

```
__init__
__init__ error
__del__
exit main
end of file
```

Comment: Yes, of course the new instance will be cleared; an exception during construction (which includes calling the `__init__` initialiser) means the new object can't be returned; the exception broke the normal flow, no assignment takes place, and no references are left. If you used `inst = A.__new__(A)` and `inst.__init__()` you would still have a reference to the object and `__del__` would *not* be called. This has nothing to do with `__init__`, it is a normal method.

Comment: I'm not sure what all this has to do with reusing the `__init__` method on an existing instance however.

Comment: Also, the `TypeError` is thrown by the code that calls `__init__`; the method is not special, only the caller is (but no more so that other code that uses special methods that break their agreed-to contract; try returning something other than a string from `__str__` for example). Call the `__init__` method directly and nothing happens if you returned something from it other than `None`.

Comment: @ Martijn Pieters, you are right. Just add this comment to your answer and it will be the best and accepted.

Comment: I'm not sure that details on how `__init__` is being called when a new instance is created matter to your style question. Your question certainly didn't try to return something from `__init__`, and any code that tried to conditionally return something would be rather confusing. At that point factoring out the portion that needs to return something would be a much better choice.