# python: Calling derived __init__ from the base class, multiple constructors problem

Tags: python, class, constructor, multiple-inheritance

I'm trying to do protocol decoding in Python.

Short version of my question:

- I have received an array of bytes that is a packet of data.

  - Using the first byte of the packet, I know what type of packet it is.
  - Using that - I want to construct a packet via a class.
- When i want to send a packet, really need to reuse about 90% of the processing done in the same packet class so that I can construct and send a packet.

I can do one of the above, I can't seem to do both

For example - something like this:

```py
class PacketType123(BasePacketType):

    def __init__fromparams( self, field1, field2 ):
        # called when you want to send a packet
        # ... initialize like I'am sending the packet
        self.field1 = field1
        self.field2 = field2

    def encode_and_send(self,destination):
        # encode into raw byte
        databytes = self.encode()
        destination.send( databytes )

    # called when a packet is received on the wire
    def __init__frombytearray( self, bytearray ):
        self.decode_bytearray( bytearray )
        print("Hi Field2 = %d" % self.field2 )

# create packet decode lookup table.
lookuptable = dict()
# populate it with classes
lookuptable[123] = PacketType123
# other packets would added to the lookup table
lookuptable[44] = PacketType44
lookuptable[12] = PacketType12
```

To send

```
   p1 = PacketType1( 42, "dogs and cats" )
   p1.encode_and_send( server )
```

To process incomming data, do this:

```
   databytes = receive_message()

   packet = lookuptable[ datbytes[0] ].__init__frombytearray(databytes)
```

My problem is I can do either the ToSend or the ProcessIncomming, I don't know how to do both with the same class.

I've looked over:

- [May __init__ be used as normal method for initialization, not as constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40588239/may-init-be-used-as-normal-method-for-initialization-not-as-constructor)
- [Multiple constructors in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164258/multiple-constructors-in-python)
- [What is a clean, pythonic way to have multiple constructors in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682504/what-is-a-clean-pythonic-way-to-have-multiple-constructors-in-python)
- I've seen this but I'm confused by it: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/multiprocessing/heap.py#l223

It seems the only way to make this work is with keyword args.. Yuck that complicates other things for me... Looking for other way of doing this.

Suggestions please?

Comment: The reading and linked question certainly helps to show us what/how you have got to this point, but having additional examples from how you want the API to look like for your user would be even more useful. Then again, I am guessing you might not know exactly what you want.  I am guessing that you have the `BasePacketType` class, your specific classes would inherit from that class, which will implement the specific constructors (i.e. the keyword arguments).  Your question is how to turn a `bytearray` automagically into the correct subclass?

Comment: Essentially, I would imagine doing something like `AutoPacket(some_bytearray)`, if the `some_bytearray` is decoded into something that has been registered into the lookup table, it will then produce the correct type, e.g. it would produce `PacketType1` with `field1` set to `42` and `field2` set to `"dogs and cats"`.  Let us know if this is closer to to how you imagine this API might appear.

Comment: Also it would be useful to explain why you can't do both in the same class, when you essentially almost have a working implementation - I think what you are missing is to declare both `decode_bytearray` and `__init__frombytearray` as `classmethod`, and that `decode_bytearray` need to return something rather than setting some attributes inside the implementation.  It would be useful to include what your current implementation is for the line that invoked `self.decode_bytearray( bytearray )`.

Comment: metatoaster - You have exactly what I'm trying to do:

Comment: @metatoaster - There are two use cases, case (A) is I want to send a packet, so create that type of packet/class.  The class/packet contains an array of fields, each field is a small dict - with a "field_name", "type" (u8, u16, etc), and "description" Some fields are a bit more complex (enumerations which are further decoded).  In the send case, you populate the  thing.field['name'].value = 123, and then later thing.encoded_and_send(), when the packet comes back the same array is used to decode the byte stream back into the field array.

Comment: @metatoast - I don't exactly get the idea of what a class method is.  The other way to describe what I want is this:  if I have a BaseMessage, how do I transform it upto a more complex class.   For example,  I receive a message: I can tell that it is a graphic object, and not an audio message. But in the end, would like that 'basic message' transformed into a graphic message, then transformed into for example a "triangle' or 'square' message.  The problem is that there is no way to overload the __init__ function.

Comment: A `classmethod` is basically like an ordinary method, except it can be invoked directly without an instance of the class, and that the implicit `self` is replaced with the class itself - which allows the method to return not just anything, but also be allowed the access to the class to construct a new instance of the class (or any subclass automatically) and return.  A better example would be the `setuptools` [`EntryPoint.parse`](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/v45.2.0/pkg_resources/__init__.py#L2480) classmethod, it returns an `EntryPoint` instance from a `str`.

Comment: To be even more explicit - `classmethod` is a very useful way to define alternative constructors for any given class in a way that can be propagated to any of their subclasses, without having to override the `__init__` method to accept alternative arguments - generally speaking, this applies if the constructors can generate those arguments, but there are ways to also side-step this using `__new__` (see one of the [linked answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38885481) in one of the threads you've linked).

Comment: One last thing: to reiterate, if you provide an example implementation of `decode_bytearray` I would be in a better position to provide an answer.